# Compile OpenSSH for use in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, openssh

I am trying to create an application to take advantage of OpenSSH to create an sFtp client for the iphone. I know that it is possible to create ssh clients for iPhone (iSSH, TouchTerm, etc) and I also assume they are using openssh as a base.

Would I just need to create a static library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this question has [already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034745/iphone-using-c-libraries).  Short answer: you can drop the source files into your project and compile them with the application, or you could probably link to a static library (if it's OK with their license--it's not OK with LGPL, for instance, but I think it should be OK with OpenSSH).  Hope that helps.